# Is it possible to cast shadows from a sillouethe made by alpha texture?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, light

It is possible to get/cast a shadow from the image on the 3D plane with alpha?

[image]

Comment: blender internal? If yes please add it as tag.

Comment: Yes, use the *Receive Transparent* option

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: It was already answered, I was looking for the Duplicate question. Figured I'd give an answer while I found it

Comment: I activated Receive Transparent, but it doesnt work.

Comment: activate cast in material settings, check your light settings for shadows